# How to iterate nested XML data in actionscript or as3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

This is my XML data

```
public var treeData:XML =  <item name="vCenter Server" type="Server">
   <item name = "Datacenter" type="Datacenter" checked="false" moid="datacenter-85">
        <item name = "Cluster1" type="ClusterComputeResource" checked="false"  value="one" moid="cluster-85">
            <item  name = "Host1" ctype="Cluster1" type="HostSystem" checked="false" value="one" moid="hostystem-85"/>
            <item  name = "Host2" ctype="Cluster1" type="HostSystem" checked="false" value="one" moid="hostystem-86"/>
        </item>
         <item name = "Cluster2" type="ClusterComputeResource" checked="false" value="two" moid="cluster-86">
            <item name = "Host3" ctype="Cluster2" type="HostSystem" checked="false" value="two" moid="hostystem-87"/>
            <item name = "Host4" ctype="Cluster2" type="HostSystem" checked="false" value="two" moid="hostystem-88"/>
        </item>
        <item name = "Host 3" type="HostSystem" checked="true" moid="hostystem-89"> </item>
        <item name = "Host 4" type="HostSystem" checked="false" moid="hostystem-90"> </item>
   </item>  
</item>;
```

How can I iterate over the nested xml data in actionscript and show alerts:

if **checked** value is **true**, show **You have selected**

if **checked** value is **false**, show  **you have not selected in any item**.

I have done following code but it is not working.

```
override public function isValid():Boolean
{
    if(treeData == null){
        Alert.show("Empty tree")
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for each(var item:XML in treeData)
        {

            for each(var item:XML in server.item.item)
            {
                if(item.@checked != true)
                {
                    Alert.show("You have not selected any item");
                    return false;
                }
                else if(item.@checked == true){
                    Alert.show("You have selected item");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;    
    }

}
```

I am iterating this xml on checkbox functionality

Comment: Are you trying to verify that all items are checked or just one that should be checked ? Could you explain more your problem ?

Comment: @akmozo i am trying to verify just one that should be checked

Comment: @Rushikeshjogle I edited your question to improve the code formatting, and I rephrased your question in hopes of making it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify life using [E4X](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/ECMAscript_for_XML) ( [ECMAScript for XML](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/ECMAscript_for_XML) ) to get the number of the selected items from your xml content like this :

```
trace(
    xml.*.(@checked == 'true').length() +       // level : 1 ( Datacenter ), gives : 0
    xml.*.*.(@checked == 'true').length() +     // level : 2 ( Cluster1, Cluster2, Host 3, Host 4 ), gives : 1
    xml.*.*.*.(@checked == 'true').length()     // level : 3 ( Host1, Host2, Host3, Host4 ), gives : 0
);      
// gives : 1
```

For more details about working with XML in AS3, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you very much :) It Worked